# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for

Tags: java, jsp, struts

in struts 1.2 using

```
<bean:include page="URL of another Struts action within application">
```

this line causing the error

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

401 is for Unauthorized wondering why it is throwing me this error.

Comment: Read docs: http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/struts-bean.html#include.

Comment: I am not sure there is something which will resolve my issue it was working fine in my local env, but on UAT machine it is throwing this issue